# How to contact an api many times a minute?

Tags: python, api, proxy, ddos

Hello I need to create an application that contacts the api shopify, stripe, facebook api and many others. I contact as many times the api as I have customer in my application to update information in my database. I integrate for each user these different api every 30 minutes. So if I have 100 users I will contact 100 times the shopify api... every 30 minutes.
My script is in python and I use request. I wanted to use a new proxy for each request because I make many requests. However even with a proxy I get a message from webshare that provides me with proxies "We have received potential abuse reports from our network partners with the following reason: brute-force attempts on payment gateways." So here is my question how I can contact many times api every second without being blocked for ddos. My current script in python

```
s = requests.session()
s.proxies['http'] = 'socks5h://' + proxy_information
s.proxies['https'] = 'socks5h://' + proxy_information
server_proxies = s.proxies
response = requests.get(url, auth=(token, ''), proxies=server_proxies, params=param_data)
```

Comment: Spread them out. If you have 100 users, do 3-4 every minute.

Comment: is it not possible to do a batch request?